# Aligning equations that also include text

Tags: tables, lists

I am trying to align a list of 
descriptions of various variables used in a statistical analysis. 
In case it is relevant, the
text-width of a single column is 75mm.

I have tried various environments (tabular, tabularx) 
but don't have a good solution.
My current best is

```
Mauris suscipit risus dapibus urna 
fermentum, sed placerat leo tincidunt. 
Vivamus sit amet laoreet ante. 
Nulla in egestas turpis. 
\vspace{-9mm}%
\begin{list}{}
  \item
    \begin{equation*}
    y = 
      \begin{cases}
        1 & \textrm{condition for variable to be unity} \\
        0 & \textrm{condition for variable to be zero} \\[+1.5mm]
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
%  
  \item{$x_1$}
     = very long description with lots of words of the first $x$ variable
%
  \item{$x_2$}
     = very long description with lots of words of the second $x$ variable.
%
\end{list}
\vspace{2mm}\noindent
Aenean consequat sapien venenatis, 
sollicitudin tellus nec, 
sollicitudin lectus. 
Curabitur eget pulvinar justo.
```

This aligns the left edge of the list and, perhaps by luck, aligns the 
equals (=) signs but runs the continuing lines under the beginning of 
the item descriptions instead of indenting them. It also has the ugliness of 
too much manual adjustment to the vertical spacing!

Suggestions please ...

Comment: ...turpis.
\begin{description}
  \item[]
    \begin{equation*}
    y = 
      \begin{cases}
        1 & \textrm{condition for variable to be unity} \\
        0 & \textrm{condition for variable to be zero}
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation*}
  \item[$x_1$]
     = very long description with lots of words of the first $x$ variable
  \item[$x_2$]
     = very long description with lots of words of the second $x$ variable.
\end{description}
\noindent
Aenean...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example uses a combination of a modified `quote` environment, packages `tabularx`, `array` and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  columnsep=5mm,
  textwidth=155mm,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newenvironment{leftquote}{%
  \list{}{}%
  \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
\newenvironment{vardesc}{%
  \newcommand*{\nextvar}{%
    \tabularnewline
    \addlinespace
  }%
  \leftquote
  \tabularx{\linewidth}{@{}>{$}l<{$}@{${}={}$}X@{}}%
}{%
  \endtabularx
  \endleftquote
}

\begin{document}
  Mauris suscipit risus dapibus urna
  fermentum, sed placerat leo tincidunt.
  Vivamus sit amet laoreet ante.
  Nulla in egestas turpis.
  \begin{vardesc}
     y &
      $\begin{cases}
        1 & \textrm{condition for variable to be unity} \\
        0 & \textrm{condition for variable to be zero}
      \end{cases}$
    \nextvar
    x_1 &
      very long description with lots of words of the first $x$ variable.
    \nextvar
    x_2 &
      very long description with lots of words of the second $x$ variable.
  \end{vardesc}
  Aenean consequat sapien venenatis,
  sollicitudin tellus nec,
  sollicitudin lectus.
  Curabitur eget pulvinar justo.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Explanation:**

The left indentation and the vertical spacing around the variable description block looks like a `quote` environment, but without the right indentation. Therefore the example defines environment `leftquote`, which copies the definition of `quote`, but without reducing the line width on the right.

The vertical alignments for the symbols and the equal signs are achieved via a table:

- The symbols are left aligned (column type `l`) and set in math mode (`>{$}l<{$}`).
- The equals sign is put into the column specification `@{${}={}$}`. This avoids that the user has to type it for each variable and ensures consistent spacing. The empty groups around the equal sign are subformulas and TeX adds the usual space around it.
- The right description column should span the available space, therefore column type `X` and the table environment `tabularx` are used.
- Additional `\tabcol` spaces at the left and right side of the table are suppressed by `@{}`.
- There is additional space between the variables. This is set by `\addlinespace` of package `booktabs`. Together with the previous end of the table row (`\tabularnewline`), it is put into a new macro `\newvar`, which ends the current table row and sets the vertical space between variable descriptions.

Comment: I really appreciated this answer. It worked beautifully, which is always a bonus. More than that, it seemed to answer more than the specific problem that occurred in this document and highlighted an approach one might use for other similar challenges.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[active,displaymath,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
    \begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
1.  &&  
    y = & \begin{cases}
            1 & \textrm{condition for variable to be unity} \\
            0 & \textrm{condition for variable to be zero} \\[+1.5mm]
        \end{cases}
        &    \\
    &&
    x_1 = &\ \parbox[t]{88mm}{very very very very very very very long description with lots of words of the first $x$ variable}
        &   \\
    &&
    x_2 = &\ \parbox[t]{88mm}{very very very very very very very long description with lots of words of the second $x$ variable}
        & 
\end{flalign*}
    \end{document}
```

Adjust the width of parbox to accommodate width of your column.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this as an answer, since my comment formatting gets messed up.  I think you are making things too complicated, and so is the other answer.  What's wrong with this?

```
...turpis.
\begin{description}
  \item $y=
      \begin{cases}
        1 & \textrm{condition for variable to be unity} \\
        0 & \textrm{condition for variable to be zero}
      \end{cases}$
  \item[$x_1=$]
     very long description with lots of words of the first $x$ variable
  \item[$x_2=$]
     very long description with lots of words of the second $x$ variable.
\end{description}
\noindent
Aenean...
```

Comment: Indeed, one might think that this would work. I tried something very similar before posting my question. But, it does not work. The alignment goes wrong with the equation being more indented than the other descriptions, probably because (I'm not a TeX expert!) the empty item[] is still using space.

Comment: That's because it's being centered :)  I'm editing my answer to get rid of the centering.  It's even simpler now.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. The obvious syntax errors (the $ preceding the y has no corresponding closure, and the equation* end has no corresponding beginning) prevent correct parsing. Resolving the syntax errors by substituting the opening $ with \begin{equation*} still results in incorrect formatting.

Comment: My apologies.  Copy/paste error.  Fixing now.

Comment: This is nice. Thank you. I had not realised that it was possible to use a \begin{... inside a $-initiated mathmode. I had thought it only worked inside another \begin{... environment. So, I've learned something. Second, the indentation is somewhat different from the solution of Heiko Oberdeik. I prefer his indentation ... but nonetheless, if your posted solution had worked initially, or even after the first revision, I undoubtedly would have marked the answer as correct because of its simplicity.